# $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-2z+2}$ - Maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization

Let the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-2z+2}$. I have to find $\max_{z \in D(0,1)} |f(z)|$, but I already know that the maxixum would be on $\bar{D}-interior(D)$ by the maximum modulus principle. Is anyone could help me how to find the maximum on $\bar{D}-interior(D)$?

Comment: Note that $z=e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ on the boundary and find the minimum of $\lvert 1/f(z)\rvert$.

Comment: You are absolutely right!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is equivalent to finding the **minimum** modulus of $(z-1)^2+1$ over $\|z\|\leq 1$.

That happens for $z=e^{i\theta}$: in such a case,
$$ \left\|(z-1)^2+1\right\|^2 = (\cos(2\theta)-2\cos\theta+1)^2+(\sin(2\theta)-2\sin\theta)^2$$
or:
$$ \left\|(z-1)^2+1\right\|^2 = 4(\cos^2\theta-\cos\theta)^2 + 4(\cos\theta-1)^2(1-\cos^2\theta) $$
or:
$$ \left\|(z-1)^2+1\right\|^2 = 16 \sin^4\frac{\theta}{2}. $$
The question is now trivial.

Comment: So the minimum is zero, right? Because the derivative $(\sqrt{16 \sin^4\frac{\theta}{2}})'=2 \sin \theta =0 \implies \theta =0 $. The answer of my teacher is $\sqrt{ \frac{1}{2}}$ for the minimum and $\sqrt{2}$ for the maximum, but I dont know where is my mistake.